# 2 fingers touch UIWebview, make my app crash

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, crash, uitouch

**UPDATE**

I'm looking for the best way to detect more than one finger on a particular view at time in this case the view is UITextview. I'm not detecting taps or pinching, just the fact that more than one touch is happening. In this case, i set `textview.multipleTouchEnabled=NO` and then i didn't set gesture anywhere. And i didn't set the zoom in UITextView. And i didn't override some of touches method in that controller.

the problem is, when i touch my app on the device using a touch like pinching, or touch use more than one finger, the app got crashed and no error log in the debugger console. I try to debug this app, but i dont know what i'm looking for.

**UPDATE 2**

i was  wrong about the object that get user touch, i was thought that the object is UITextview, but UIWebview. So, this problem is happen when i touch UIWebview with 2 fingers. I have forwarded the touches event using [this suggestion](http://ryan-brubaker.blogspot.com/2009/01/iphone-sdk-uiwebview.html). But i still confuse, how to clear up this crash on my app.
Can somebody help me??

Thank You

Regard,

Risma

Comment: Have you ever override touch handling methods such as `touchesBegin:withEvent:`?

Comment: i have using a MGSplitView library, on that library there is one overriding touchesMoved method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that text view zoom level is set by default it's min and max zoom is 1.

In pinch gesture you have to set scale factor.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i don't want to set the pinch gesture. is textview zoom level that you mean is zoomScale??

Comment: yes like scrollview you can zoom textview.

http://www.ikangai.com/blog/uncategorized/code-snippet-of-the-week-uitextview-text-zoom

this like may help you.